# How to send 3 params to a metod in js from MVC View?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I Need to send 3 parameters: a checkbox,an int and a string from a Razor View to a js method:

**The HTML/Razor code:**

```
<td><input type="checkbox" class="multi_checkbox" onclick="selected(this,@item.Id,@item.Status)"></td>
```

**My js method**

```
function selected(checkbox, id, status) {
if (checkbox.checked) {
        console.log("added: " + id);
        checkedRows.push(id);
    } else {
        console.log("deleted: " + id);
        for (var i = 0; i < checkedRows.length; i++) {
            if (checkedRows[i] === id) {
                checkedRows.splice(i, id);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(checkedRows);
}
```

When i work in this way it throws me an error:

> (index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Rejected is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):1)

*Rejected* is the value of `@item.Status` which is a string with that value.

Comment: Not very clear what you want to achieve... I'd recommend to figure out what JavaScript you want to generate and then make sure CSHTML produces that exact HTML+JavaScript… At this point only guess can be made you want `"Rejected"` as parameter when you get `Rejected` instead... but that's not clear - please [edit] post to clarify.

Comment: When I send 3 parameters it throws me the error, but if I use 2 parameters (checkbox and Id) it works well, I use it to evaluate if status is the same in the selected items (checkbox inside a td).

Comment: Status is a string or enum?

Comment: did it make any change if you change this to single quotes - onclick='selected(this,@item.Id,@item.Status)'

Comment: Status is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code to handle the string value of status.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" class="multi_checkbox" onclick="selected(this,@item.Id,'@item.Status')"></td>
```

Notice now '@item.Status' has single quotes around it so that it will be passed as a string. Keep an eye on the different data types you are passing in JavaScript and good luck!!